# How to use nsupdate to create NAPTR record

Tags: domain-name-system

What's a working example for creating a NAPTR record using nsupdate against Bind9?

man nsupdate sais:

```
update add {domain-name} {ttl} [class] {type} {data...}
       Adds a new resource record with the specified ttl, class and data.
```

But I can't seem to find the correct format for NAPTR

My attempt:

```
echo -e 'update add enum.example.com 60 IN NAPTR 1.1.1.1.1."u"."E2U+sip"."!^.*$!test123test@example.com!" .'"\nsend"|nsupdate
```

results in:

```
invalid rdata format: not a valid number
syntax error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working example:

```
echo -e "nsupdate "update add 1.2.3.4 60 IN NAPTR 100 10 \"u\" \"E2U+h323\" \"!^.*$!test@example.com!\" ."\nserver localhost\nsend" | /usr/bin/nsupdate -y rndckey:mykey -v
```